# TestCafe - How can I run multiple fixtures (one after the other, not concurrent)?

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, code-organization, web-testing, testcafe

I have multiple fixtures (interaction between a website and a hybrid app) and I would like to have a test suite run (Smoke test, regression test ...) but I'm not sure how to do it.

This is how my tests look like:

[image]

What I want to do is run all tests (eg. CreatePollAndCloseIt.js, CreatePollPinAndDelete.js, CreateStreamAssertions.js and so on until the last one VotePollWhitelabel ) and get a report after.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run all your tests by specifying the parent folder of your test file. For example you can run all your `Mobile Tests` with the command:
`testcafe chrome <path>/MobileTests`

Also it's possible to reorganize your folder structure, eg:

```
 - Mobile
     - Smoke
     - Regression
```

In this case you can run your test suites via following commands:

- `testcafe chrome <path>/Mobile` - for all tests
- `testcafe chrome <path>/Mobile/Smoke` - only smoke
- `testcafe chrome <path>/Mobile/Regression` - only regression

Another way to organize the test-suites is using the testing metadata. Please refer to the following articles to get the details:

- [Specifying Testing Metadata](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#specifying-testing-metadata)
- [Filtering by Testing Metadata](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--fixture-meta-keyvaluekey2value2)